# Ed25519 choice of private key implementation

Tags: public-key, implementation, ed25519

[This answer to another question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3606/7770) describes the different values chosen as private key and public key by various Ed25516 implementations. What are the advantages / disadvantages of each?

[image: Different Ed25519 private key and signature formats for NaCl, SUPERCOP and python-ed25519]

(Table cropped from diagram in the linked answer, originally taken from ["How do Ed5519 keys work?"](http://blog.mozilla.org/warner/2011/11/29/ed25519-keys/) by Brian Warner.)

Comment: I don't really get your question. Which different methods are you talking about? if you don't have any special requirements you should simply follow the spec, which derives the private scalar and a second key by hashing a 32 byte seed with SHA-512.

Comment: I think you are confused. The table on the bottom of the picture describes various APIs, but they implement the same cryptographic scheme.

Comment: I disagree; the table does show differences in what makes up 'a private key'.  Now, the differences are fairly minor; however asking for someone to explain those differences would appear to be relevant.

Comment: @poncho Those differences are only memory/cpu time tradeoffs and all functionally equal.

Comment: @poncho. You are correct, I'm asking about the pros/cons of using a/RH vs k/A as the private key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform an Ed25519 signature operation, you need to know three values, denoted by $\sf RH$, $a$ and $A$ in [the diagram](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3606/598).  Now, as it happens, these values are not independent:

- $A$ can be derived from $a$, and
- both $\sf RH$ and $a$ can be derived from the seed $k$.

Thus, all you really *need* to store is the seed $k$; everything else can be derived from it.  Alternatively, it's possible to store $\sf RH$ and $a$ like NaCl does, which saves you the (minor) effort of one SHA-512 hash computation whenever you need to sign something.

There's no particular need to store the public key $A$ as part of the private key, since it can be derived from $a$ and you need to know $a$ anyway to be able to sign.  However, deriving $A$ from $a$ requires an elliptic curve multiplication, which is a reasonably expensive operation compared to the other key generation steps.  Thus, also storing $A$ as part of the private key provides a modest performance gain compared to storing just $k$ or just $\sf RH$ and $a$.